# How to write a custom condition that only runs an agent phase if a previous agent phase has been run - Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to write a custom condition for an agent phase that means that it only runs if a previous (or specific) agent phase has been run, regardless of whether it passes or fails.

For example...

[image]

So I would only like to run **Sequential Tests** if **Parallel Tests** has been run. If **Parallel Tests** is skipped, I would also like **Sequential Tests** to be skipped.

I had a look here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=yaml

...but couldn't find an equivalent example.

Thanks,

Comment: You are asking two questions in one.

Comment: i dont think thats possible without yaml

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono please explain where the 2 questions are. The question is can you create a custom condition that runs an agent phase only if another agent phase has been run, regardless of failure or success.

Comment: @Konzy262 one question is asking about how to write a custom condition for an agent phase that means that it only runs if a previous (or specific) agent phase has been run, regardless of whether it passes or fails. Next  question is how to to run Sequential Tests if Parallel Tests has been run. These are different questions.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I agree. It's not possible in current Azure DevOps build designer. It's only possible using YAML. Also only YAML has support for default parallel multi jobs.

Comment: @Eriawan Kusumawardhono No. 'Sequential Tests' and 'Parallel Tests' are in reference to the screenshot which you must not have seen. The screenshot clearly shows these are examples of agent phases. This is an example of how I would like to run a custom condition whereby the 'Sequential Tests' agent phase is run after the 'Parallel Tests' agent phase, only if the 'Sequential Tests' phase has been run.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to know about the release pipelines at the moment, is that the agent phases do not support parallel execution yet like the build pipelines.  The phases will execute in sequential order.  Since that is true, I would think you could just use the same conditional that you used to skip/run the first phase.

```
and(always(), eq(variables[ExecuteTests], True))
```

Comment: No, the asker is asking about build pipeline conditions, not release pipeline conditions.

Comment: Did you look at the provided screenshot at all?  The agent phase has options for artifact download that is only available on a phase in a release pipeline.  And the release option at the top is only visible on a release pipeline.  Also the question is using the tag azure-pipelines-release-pipeline.  I'm pretty sure my answer is scoped to what was asked.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. The first phase ('Parallel Tests') is skipped using the condition `Only when all previous jobs have succeeded`. I can't use this same option for the 'Sequential Tests' agent phase as I want it to run regardless of whether 'Parallel Tests' has any failures or not, and also skip if 'Parallel Tests' is skipped. Isn't `and(always(), eq(variables[ExecuteTests], True))` an always run regardless condition?